# C# Fastest way to search on a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I've created a text manager class that handles texts for different contexts (for example: general context, menu context, game context, etc...).

Every context is created using a binary text file, and the data is stored in a dictionary within a dictionary like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> m_TextContexs;
```

Which works like this:

```
m_TextContexs[context][textID][actual text]
```

I would like that the user finds any line of text only with the '`textID`' string in a function like this:

```
public string GetText(string id)
```

Edited: textIDs are unique, in the sense that the same textID will not exist in multiple contexts.

So this function should find the string id in all the existing contexts and return the valid actual text.

The question here would be, what is the fastest way to do this operation. I am not an experienced programmer, so what I would do is cycle through all the contexts and look inside each of them if it the mention text ID exists.

If you are wondering why I need the 'context' is to group texts, so if a context is no longer needed I can unload that data from memory.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you provide a better example of what you mean by "dictionary within a dictionary"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by fastest? Performance? Time spent to code? What about other considerations like memory usage, etc?

Comment: NightOwl888 by searching in a dictionary within a dictionary I mean the line I wrote above for the object m_TextContexts. The key of the main dictionary are many contexts like c1, c2, c3, etc... Within each contexts there is a dictionary containing the actual pairs of texts. So for example the textID "id001" can be in any key of the main dictionary. But it is unique (as in it is not repeated across different contexts).

Comment: AndrewP, sorry about the ambiguity of my question, yes, by fastest I meant performance wise.

Comment: Thanks Amit for editing my question and making it more readable.

Answer (score 4):

Dictionaries retrieve values from keys in O(1) time, meaning practically instantly, so this question really hinges on what sort of animal your `context` is, and how unique `textId` is.

How will you know which context is the "right" one? Can you determine this from the user's current location from and path within the app? If so, then you can pass *that* value to the lookup function.

Otherwise, looping through the contexts will do you no good unless `textId` is unique across contexts. For example, given `textId 123`, how will you know whether you want `m_TextContexs[context1][123]` or `m_TextContexs[context2][123]`?

If `textId` *is* unique across contexts (best case scenario), then you can simply eliminate `context` from the picture, and use a `Dictionary<string, string>` with `textId` being the sole key.

Comment: And if textId is unique, but context also important, perhaps flip the original dictionary so it has textId as key, and a struct/class with context/text as value, meaning you could still very easily find all values with a given context by doing a linq query against values

Comment: Thanks Paul Smith, I'm an idiot an I didn't consider same IDs in multiple contexts. I'll make sure IDs are unique when I export all the texts from the Excel file. Assuming this, the point that AndrewP makes about flipping the original dictionary makes sense. Many thanks guys!

Comment: Paul Smith and Andrew - I am still not sure what is the best and fastest (performance wise) to implement this algorithm. Assuming textIDs are unique, I'd like to avoid having the main key as textID and then the value be a struct or class with the actual text string and context string, because that means the context will be in memory as many times as texts are within the dictionary, seems a waste of memory. I'd like to keep the context, so when I want to unload a context due to their texts being no longer needed, I can quickly do it by just releasing the context key in the main dictionary.

Comment: If you can provide a few examples the textId and context values—especially highlighting when they coincide and when they differ—I can probably offer some more specific advice.